# Errors When Compiling Multiple .hpp and .cpp Files in c++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, header-files

I just started a CS degree and I'm brand new to actual programming and hence the implementation is proving difficult. I recently had an assignment that left me stumped. I was stumped because I was unable to link all the files together (2 header files .hpp and 2 implementation files .cpp). The assignment has come and gone I'm just curious as to how I would link all the files together since I know that when it comes to compile time the Board.hpp and Board.cpp files will compile into one file and the TicTacToe.hpp and TicTacToe.cpp files will compile into one file AND then all of the two compiled files will be linked to each other to produce the executable file.

Here is the error I get when I try to compile in g++:

```
TicTacToe.hpp:1:9: warning: #pragma once in main file
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have no idea what any of that means.

I'll post the files below for your reviewing. I appreciate any help you can give. Again, I'm brand new at this so if you could explain things simply I would really appreciate it.

Board.hpp

```
#ifndef BOARD_HPP
#define BOARD_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class TTTBoard
{
private:
char Board[3][3];           //creates array
int play();                 // prototype for play function
void makeMove();            //prototype for makeMove function
int turn(int);              //prototype for turn function
int check(int, int);        //prototypr for check function
void print(char x[][3]);    //prototype for print function
int gameState(char x[][3]); //prototype for gameState fuction
int player1, player2, draw, player, winner, done;   //creates variables to be used.
int row, col;               //creates variables to be used in gamestate function

public:
int TtlGames, TtlP1, TtlP2, TtlDraws;   //creates variables that will define gamestate
void intBoard();                        //prototype for intboard
};
#endif
```

The next one is kind of long.

Board.cpp

```
    #include "Board.hpp"

    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>


    void TTTBoard::intBoard()               //function to initialize the board
    {                                       //initialzes the variables in order
    done = false;                       // to be used for later functions
    winner = 0;
    player = 2;
    player1 = 1;
    player2 = 2;
    draw = 3;
    int i, k;
    for (k = 0; k<3; k++)               //initializes array to 0
    {
        for (i = 0; i<3; i++)
        {
            Board[k][i] = 0;
        }
    }
    play();                             //begins the game
    }


    int TTTBoard::check(int row, int col)   //checks if spot if occupied
    {
    if (Board[row][col] == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (Board[row][col] != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "That square is already taken.";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Checking for win.";
        gameState(Board);
    }
    return false;
    }

    void TTTBoard::makeMove()           //records players move
    {
    player = turn(player);
    int answer = false;
    while (answer == false)
    {
        std::cout << "Player" << turn(player) << ": please enter your move\n";
        std::cin >> row, col;
        answer = check(row, col);
    }

    if (player == 1)
        Board[row][col] = 'X';
    else if (player == 2)
        Board[row][col] = 'O';
    else
        std::cout << "Failed.";
}

int TTTBoard::gameState(char x[][3])    //checks for a win or a draw
{
    winner = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int a = row;
    int b = col;
    for (a = 0; a<3; a++)
    {
        for (b = 0; b<3; b++)
        {
            if (Board[a][b] == 0)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (count > 0)
    {
        int row, col, xCheck, oCheck;
        for (row = 0; row<3; row++)
        {
            xCheck = 0;
            oCheck = 0;

            for (col = 0; col<3; col++)
            {
                if (x[row][col] == 'X')
                    xCheck++;
                if (x[row][col] == 'O')
                    oCheck++;
                if (oCheck == 3)
                {
                    winner = 2;
                }
                if (xCheck == 3)
                {
                    winner = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        for (col = 0; col<3; col++)
        {
            xCheck = 0;
            oCheck = 0;
            for (row = 0; row<3; row++)
            {
                if (x[row][col] == 'X')
                    xCheck++;
                if (x[row][col] == 'O')
                    oCheck++;
                if (oCheck == 3)
                {
                    winner = 2;
                }
                if (xCheck == 3)
                {
                    winner = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        if (x[0][0] == 'X' && x[1][1] == 'X' && x[2][2] == 'X')
        {
            winner = 1;
        }
        else if (x[0][0] == 'O' && x[1][1] == 'O' && x[2][2] == 'O')
        {
            winner = 2;
        }
        else if (x[2][0] == 'X' && x[1][1] == 'X' && x[0][2] == 'X')
        {
            winner = 1;
        }
        else if (x[2][0] == 'O' && x[1][1] == 'O' && x[0][2] == 'O')
        {
            winner = 2;
        }
    }
    else if (count == 9)
    {
        std::cout << "Its a draw.";
        winner = 3;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "It is the next players turn\n\n";
    }
    if (winner > 0)
    {
        done = true;
    }
    return done;
}


void TTTBoard::print(char Board[][3])       //prints current board state
{
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "  0  1  2\n";
    std::cout << "0 " << Board[0][0] << "  " << Board[0][1] << "  " << Board[0][2] << " \n";
    std::cout << "1 " << Board[1][0] << "  " << Board[1][1] << "  " << Board[1][2] << " \n";
    std::cout << "2 " << Board[2][0] << "  " << Board[2][1] << "  " << Board[2][2] << " \n";
}
```

This one is also long.

TicTacToe.hpp

```
#ifndef TICTACTOE_HPP
#define TICTACTOE_HPP

#include "Board.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

class Board;        //creates a board to be forward declared

class TicTacToe     //creates tictactoe class
{
private:
    int check(int, int);
    int turn(int player);
    int play();                     //prototype for play method
    int gameState(char x[][3]);
public:
    int TtlGames, TtlP1, TtlP2, TtlDraws;
    void intBoard();
    Board* playBoard;               //forward declarations for use in functions
    Board* print;
    Board* makeMove;
    Board* BoardT;
};

#endif
```

TicTacToe.cpp

```
#include "Board.hpp"
#include "TicTacToe.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void TTTBoard::intBoard()       //initializes board
{
    done = false;
    winner = 0;
    player = 2;
    player1 = 1;
    player2 = 2;
    draw = 3;
    int i, k;
    for (k = 0; k<3; k++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i<3; i++)
        {
            Board[k][i] = 0;
        }
    }
    play();
}

int TicTacToe::turn(int player)         //informs players of whose turn it is.
{
    switch (player)
    {
    case 1: player = 2;
    {
        std::cout << "\nPlayers 1 turn.\n\n";
        break;
    }
    case 2: player = 1;
    {
        std::cout << "\nPlayers 2 turn.\n\n";
        break;
    }
    }
    return player;
}

int TTTBoard::gameState(char x[][3])        //checks for win or draw
{
    winner = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int a = row;
    int b = col;
    for (a = 0; a<3; a++)
    {
        for (b = 0; b<3; b++)
        {
            if (Board[a][b] == 0)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (count > 0)
    {
        int row, col, xCheck, oCheck;
        for (row = 0; row<3; row++)
        {
            xCheck = 0;
            oCheck = 0;

            for (col = 0; col<3; col++)
            {
                if (x[row][col] == 'X')
                    xCheck++;
                if (x[row][col] == 'O')
                    oCheck++;
                if (oCheck == 3)
                {
                    winner = 2;
                }
                if (xCheck == 3)
                {
                    winner = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        for (col = 0; col<3; col++)
        {
            xCheck = 0;
            oCheck = 0;
            for (row = 0; row<3; row++)
            {
                if (x[row][col] == 'X')
                    xCheck++;
                if (x[row][col] == 'O')
                    oCheck++;
                if (oCheck == 3)
                {
                    winner = 2;
                }
                if (xCheck == 3)
                {
                    winner = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        if (x[0][0] == 'X' && x[1][1] == 'X' && x[2][2] == 'X')
        {
            winner = 1;
        }
        else if (x[0][0] == 'O' && x[1][1] == 'O' && x[2][2] == 'O')
        {
            winner = 2;
        }
        else if (x[2][0] == 'X' && x[1][1] == 'X' && x[0][2] == 'X')
        {
            winner = 1;
        }
        else if (x[2][0] == 'O' && x[1][1] == 'O' && x[0][2] == 'O')
        {
            winner = 2;
        }
    }
    else if (count == 9)
    {
        std::cout << "Its a draw.";
        winner = 3;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "It is the next players turn\n\n";
    }
    if (winner > 0)
    {
        done = true;
    }
    return done;
}

int TicTacToe::play()       //initializes the game
{
    int done = false;
    Board* print(Board);
    while (!done)
    {
        int count = 0;
        Board* makeMove();
        Board* (Board);
        count++;
        if (count != 9)
        {
            return !done;
        }
        else
        {
            done = true;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()              //main method
{
    TicTacToe playGame;
        playGame.TtlGames = 0, playGame.TtlP1 = 0, 
            playGame.TtlP2 = 0, playGame.TtlDraws = 0;                  //counters for total games, Player 1 Total, 
    int Winner = 0;                                                     //Player 2 Total , and Total draws.

    char done = false;

    while (!done)
    {
        // This will display before each game
        std::cout << "Let's play a game of TicTacToe\n\n";

        // Play a game and remember who won (if anyone)
        playGame.intBoard();

    }

    // Finish
    std::cout << "\n\nThank you for playing!\n";
    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I attempted the suggestion by Code Fuller but it gave me this error.

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So I thought maybe if I put the Main method in a separate file and link them all it might work. I got this:

```
/tmp/ccmSwwUz.o: In function `TTTBoard::intBoard()':
TicTacToe.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `TTTBoard::intBoard()'
/tmp/ccSwOY9D.o:Board.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccmSwwUz.o: In function `TTTBoard::gameState(char (*) [3])':
TicTacToe.cpp:(.text+0x104): multiple definition of `TTTBoard::gameState(char (*           ) [3])'
/tmp/ccSwOY9D.o:Board.cpp:(.text+0x288): first defined here
/tmp/ccSwOY9D.o: In function `TTTBoard::intBoard()':
Board.cpp:(.text+0xa7): undefined reference to `TTTBoard::play()'
/tmp/ccSwOY9D.o: In function `TTTBoard::makeMove()':
Board.cpp:(.text+0x176): undefined reference to `TTTBoard::turn(int)'
Board.cpp:(.text+0x19b): undefined reference to `TTTBoard::turn(int)'
/tmp/ccmSwwUz.o: In function `TTTBoard::intBoard()':
TicTacToe.cpp:(.text+0xa7): undefined reference to `TTTBoard::play()'
/tmp/ccz4019v.o: In function `main':
Main.cpp:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `TicTacToe::intBoard()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So then I tried compiling the Board into an object first then linking TicTacToe and Main:

```
g++ Board.o TicTacToe.cpp Main.cpp -o TTT
```

and got the following errors:

```
/tmp/cc9h5kAs.o: In function `TTTBoard::intBoard()':
TicTacToe.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `TTTBoard::intBoard()'
Board.o:Board.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/cc9h5kAs.o: In function `TTTBoard::gameState(char (*) [3])':
TicTacToe.cpp:(.text+0x104): multiple definition of `TTTBoard::gameState(char (*) [3])'
Board.o:Board.cpp:(.text+0x288): first defined here
Board.o: In function `TTTBoard::intBoard()':
Board.cpp:(.text+0xa7): undefined reference to `TTTBoard::play()'
Board.o: In function `TTTBoard::makeMove()':
Board.cpp:(.text+0x176): undefined reference to `TTTBoard::turn(int)'
Board.cpp:(.text+0x19b): undefined reference to `TTTBoard::turn(int)'
/tmp/cc9h5kAs.o: In function `TTTBoard::intBoard()':
TicTacToe.cpp:(.text+0xa7): undefined reference to `TTTBoard::play()'
/tmp/ccZlZ4Dn.o: In function `main':
Main.cpp:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `TicTacToe::intBoard()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Please post the full command you used to compile.

Comment: Side-Note: It doesn't really matter since you have include guards (`#ifndef`), but you don't want to include `Board.hpp` in `TicTacToe.cpp` since you included it in TicTacToe's header file. You also included `iostream` in every file.

Comment: I used the following command on a Linux machine:
g++ Board.hpp Board.CPP TicTacToe.hpp TicTacToe.CPP -o TicTacToe

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You trying to compile Board.cpp to executable file while it doesn't contain 'main' entrypoint. You have to compile Board.cpp to object file first:

```
gcc Board.cpp -c
```

Then you can compile TicTacToe.cpp and link it with Board.o:

```
gcc Board.o TicTacToe.cpp -o TicTacToe
```

Comment: You should wait to post until OP has added information to give your hypothesis a leg to stand on.

Comment: Error "In function `_start': (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'" is a common error causes by incorrect gcc usage I described.

Comment: Might as well edit your answer to include every possible incorrect gcc usage, relevant to the information provided by OP, resulting in that error. I'm not saying your answer *might not* be right, I'm saying there is no way to know until OP adds information to his question.

Comment: I added my comments to the original post since the errors were too long to post in this comment.

Comment: You have duplicated TTTBoard::intBoard(), TTTBoard::gameState(char x[][3]) in both Board.cpp and TicTacToe.cpp.

Comment: Then your code doesn't have definition of TTTBoard::play(), TTTBoard::turn(int), TicTacToe::intBoard(). If you fix this errors, the code will be compiled and linked correctly with two gcc commands I posted in my original answer.

Comment: Ok, so if I remove the definition of TTTBoard::play(), TTTBoard::turn(int), TicTacToe::intBoard() it should compile. Gotcha.

Question,
Do I leave the function headers and just remove the definitions? or should I remove everything?

Comment: You mess up declaration and definition. Declaration is just a signature of method, function, etc., you have them in your hpp files. Definition is a method or function body, the code itself. So you have declarations of specified methods but don't have definitions for them. But you can not just remove declarations, because these methods are called in other methods of your code, and linker will finish with error if you don't provide definitions.

Comment: I'm sorry CodeFuller. I don't fully understand what it is you're saying. I understand that a declaration is different than the definition. But how would the definition in Board.cpp file be linked to TicTactoe.cpp when the declaration is in Board.hpp and the definition is in Board.cpp?

Comment: It's the work for the linker. Compiled code (definitions) are kept in .o files, and linker then put it altogether to final executable file. So your problem for this moment that you didn't provided methods definitions I mentioned and object files (.o) are missing them, but linker searches for these definitions and fails.